# Need to keep an image at the right bottom of a div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to show number of items in a row. Each item would have two texts that need to be in the top middle of the item, an image in middle of the item and another one at the right bottom of the item.  Height of all items must be fixed and images should not overflow their border in any screen size.

I have following code, and the main issue is that I cannot keep the second images at the right bottom of their respective items.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/6y4uf16y/1/)

```css
         .items { */
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-left: 7px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #ffeecc;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 height:260px;

}



.col-md-12.col-xs-12.btn>a>img {
 float: right;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
}

.col-md-12.col-xs-12.my-col {
 padding-left: 100%;
}

.my-row {
 bottom: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.my-row {
 bottom: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.btn {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">

</head>


<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 items">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h4>T1</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h5>T2</h5>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 row text-center">
        <a
         href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
         title="T1" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
         id="imageresource"
         src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
         class="img-thumbnail" width="30%" style="margin-left: 30px;" />
        </a>

       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 my-col">
        <div>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" class="btn" /></a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>



     <div class="col-md-3 items">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h4>T1</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h5>T2</h5>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 row text-center">
        <a
         href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
         title="T1" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
         id="imageresource"
         src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
         class="img-thumbnail" width="25%" style="margin-left: 30px;" />
        </a>

       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 my-col">
        <div>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" class="btn" /></a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>


   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: There is a little icon with <> symbols in it, this is the button to add the snippet :)

Comment: thanks dingo_d. Whats the negative vote for?

Comment: Don't know, wasn't me :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue by changing the image part to following and adding below css

```
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" class="btn" /></a>
</div>


.btn {
    float: right;
    bottom:0;
    margin-right:-12px;
    margin-bottom:-6px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to image,

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

Comment: My code was not working with different size of images so I changed the code. Please have a look at updated question.

Answer (score 0):

parent element should be `position: relative`
the element to position in right bottom corner should be

```
position: absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```